# VSCode on WSL - Windows vs Linux filesystem

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Assuming I'm using vscode on wsl, and running vscode itself on Windows (via the wsl vscode extension).
Should I store my code in Windows' filesystem, or in wsl's virtual Linux filesystem?
If I ran vscode 'natively' on wsl (vscode for Ubuntu) I'd definitely use wsl's filesystem for better disk performance - but will I still benefit from it if I run it natively on Windows?

---

Comment: AFAIK, this is the one drawback of wsl2 at the moment: crossing the filesystem boundary is slow. If files are stored in ubuntu, but you open them from a windows app, it's slower than opening files stored in windows. On the other hand, ubuntu can work with them quickly. This matters if you, say, boot up a medium-large Rails app (which may consist of thousands of ruby files). So, in general, you have to decide where you want to take that performance hit: when developing or in runtime.

Comment: But with VSCode, this point may be moot. It's using a server/agent inside of ubuntu and that part may be handling opening the files.

Answer (score 0):

There's some problems when you want to remote develop on WSL:

Developing on WSL with Windows' filesystem, files watcher may not work.

[WSL2: nodemon file watcher no longer working #4169](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4169)

I think you should store your code on WSL to avoid this and better performance, but VS Code will increase amount of RAM memory usage like crazy.

[the node program high memory usage with Remote wsl #2919](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2919)

So make sure your computer has enough RAM to develop on WSL, me with 16GB of RAM is sufferring with WSL right now.